# Script to delete record from database doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to delete records with button which is placed on Index webpage. I wrote down some jQuery with AJAX, but it doesn't work.

Here is my controller method. This method works properly when I call it with use of form which is generated on another page by HttpGet Delete method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var userId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var training = _context.Trainings.Where(t => t.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
    if (training != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Trainings.Remove(training);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();            
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".js-delete").on("click", function () {
        var button = $(this);
        var trainingId = button.attr;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this training?")) {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "/Training/Delete/" + trainingId,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("ok");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("not ok");                        
            }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<button data-customer-id="@training.Id" class="btn btn-link js-delete">Usuń</button>
```

What I'm having now is: window pops-up and after I confirm I get error result generated by my script, and in console I have status: 400, type: xhr and response is:

```
http://localhost:6822/Training/Delete/function%20(%20name,%20value%20)%20%7Breturn%20access(%20this,%20jQuery.attr,%20name,%20value,%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20);%7D
```

Comment: Your making an ajax call and ajax call cannot redirect so `return RedirectToAction("Index");` makes no sense. You method does not have a parameter for a model so `ModelState.IsValid` makes no sense (its always valid). To set the value of `data-customer-id` it needs to be `var trainingId = $(this).data('customer-id');` and the ajax should be `url: "/Training/Delete/", data: { id: trainingId },` and remove `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json"` and try, because you are not using any JSON format here.
If needed also add  `dataType: "text"` and `data: { id: trainingId }`, and `url: "/Training/Delete/"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  - thank you for your help. I wrote the code according to your tips.
However I think I have problem with routing (because in console it calls Training/Delete/ and doesn't pass
It looks like this:  '
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");'
So id is optional, and i found the way how to configure it with defaults property like in MVC5, but the problem is UrlParameter.Optional doesn't work. 

Should I reconfigure my routing or write the function differently?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the routing - debug you script - inspect the value of `var trainingId = button.attr;` (it needs to be `var trainingId = $(this).data('customer-id');`. But nothing else in you code makes sense. You want to redirect when the `id` value exists and the record has been deleted (which will be 99.99% or the time) so DO NOT use ajax - its pointless.

Comment: And in the rare case of a malicious user posting an invalid `id`, you return a view to client but never even use it - its just degrading the performance of your app. And then what - are you expecting the user to click the delete button again to delete a record which no longer exists? Make a normal submit.

Comment: If on the other hand, you have multiple items and you want the user to continue to delete other items on the page, then you need to return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise and in the success callback, remove the current item from the DOM if successful

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:6822/Training/Delete/function%20(%20name,%20value%20)%20%7Breturn%20access(%20this,%20jQuery.attr,%20name,%20value,%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20);%7D
```

I think url should be something like:

```
http://localhost:6822/Training/Delete/5 (since your action expects int value in parameter.)
```

You should debug your script and see what you are getting in trainingId.

```
        var button = $(this);
        var trainingId = button.attr;
```

because here you are passing below function in parameter.
    function%20(%20name,%20value%20)%20%7Breturn%20access(%20this,%20jQuery.attr,%20name,%20value,%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20);%7D

I think you should try with:

```
 var trainingId = $(this).attr("data-customer-id")
```